# Python - None argument

Tags: python, list, arguments

I have a function with 4 arguments:

```
   def uploadDatabase(user,filter1,filter2, name):
        """uploads playlists to database

        if a playlist satisfying both filters is not long enough,
        we pick a playlist based on one single filter"""

        playlist_filter1 = [x['track'] for x in filter1]
        playlist_filter2 = [x['track'] for x in filter2]
        playlist_both_filters = [x['track'] for x in filter2 if x['track'] in [y['track'] for y in filter1]]

       #create an empty dict for user as key
       double_filter = {str(user):{}}
       single_filter1 = {str(user):{}}
       single_filter2 = {str(user):{}}
       #set initial playback number for each track
       count = 1
       #set counts to tracks
       double_filter[str(user)] = dict(zip(playlist_both_filters, [count for i in playlist_both_filters]))
       db_double = double_filter 
       #set counts to tracks
       single_filter1[str(user)] = dict(zip(playlist_filter1, [count for i in playlist_filter1]))
       db_single1 = single_filter1 
       (...)
```

however, sometimes `filter2` won't be passed:

```
uploadDatabase(user,energy_playlist, None, 'my playlist')
```

how do I fix `uploadDatabase()` and tell it to ignore `None Type` being assigned to variables `playlist_filter2` and `double_filter`, given the fact that both need valid `lists`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to check whether argument **filter2** is passed or not.

Well to do that is simple, you actually give it a **default value** of `None` and then in the code check whether the argument is `None` or not.

### Example Code

```
def uploadDatabase(user,filter1,filter2=None, name):
    if not filter2:
        # filter2 argument in not passed
    else:
        # filter2 argument is there.
```

and when you use the function you can pass filter2 and it will overwrite the default `None` value or just don't pass it and it will be `None`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `None` types to valid empty lists for both filters by doing:

```
playlist_filter1 = [x['track'] for x in filter1] if filter1 is not None else []
playlist_filter2 = [x['track'] for x in filter2] if filter2 is not None else []
```

instead of:

```
playlist_filter1 = [x['track'] for x in filter1]
playlist_filter2 = [x['track'] for x in filter2]
```

Comment: please update you answer so it fixes `playlist_both_filters = [x['track'] for x in filter2 if x['track'] in [y['track'] for y in filter1]]
`, using the `if condition`, as well